# How to add generic method to a class, that takes a class extending a generic class, ignoring it's parent template parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class with such definition:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
   ...
}
```

Now, I have a bunch of classes extending BaseRepository.
I want to create a method, that takes a child of BaseRepository as a generic parameter.
And it works perfectly fine:

```
public void Method<T, TEntity> () where T : BaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
   ...
}
```

But I don't really care what TEntity is, I just care that it's a child of BaseRepository.
I only use *T* in *Method*, therefore I would like to get rid of TEntity.
A perfect usage of my *Method* would be:

```
instance.Method<CarsRepository>();
```

Does C# offer some syntax that would allow me to ommit TEntity as a generic argument?
If not, what should I do, assuming I can't change BaseRepository syntax?

Comment: Inherit `BaseRepository<TEntity>` from another non-generic `BaseRepository` and move all non-generic methods there. Then you can have `Method<T>() where T: BaseRepository`.

Comment: If I do that, I won't be able to pass my repositories, as they inherit from BaseRepository<T>, and not from BaseRepository. I would have to change every repository to inherit from BaseRepository, and that's not what I want, if I understood you the right way.

Comment: You will be able to pass them, because in my proposal, `BaseRepository<T>` itself inherits from `BaseRepository`, so all your repositories will also automatically inherit from `BaseRepository` through `BaseRepository<T>`

Comment: Ohh, I understood to make a hierarchy BaseRepository : BaseRepository<T> with a specific object. Thanks, your solution seems like a way to go!

Comment: Another option is making `BaseRepository<TEntitiy>` implement a non genric `IBaseRepository` interface and pass that along... in your case you can choose either one, but if `BaseRepository<T>` were to already extend another base class then the interface would be the way to go.

Comment: The interface-based method (e.g. `ICarsRepository`) is the way to go